# Gradle : Passing dynamic variable from one CommandLine-task to another CommandLine-task

Tags: gradle, command-line-interface

I am new to Gradle and have problems.

How can I make gitDiff() sees tasks.gitMergBase.mergebase() ?

```
task gitMergBase(dependsOn:'initDir', type:Exec) {
    description 'git merge-base'
    commandLine "git", "merge-base" , "origin/master", "${destBranch}"
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ext.mergebase = {
        standardOutput.toString()
    }
    
}


task gitDiff(dependsOn:['initDir', 'gitMergBase'], type:Exec) {
    description 'Pulls git.'
    commandLine "git", "diff" , "--name-status" , tasks.gitMergBase.mergebase(), "${destBranch}"
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ext.diff = {
        standardOutput.toString()
    }    
}
```